# Cannot read all lines of text file in java

Tags: java, io, text-files

I'm trying to read a 50000+ lines text file in a Java web application.

I created a Java class to read the text file. While reading it adds each line to an `ArrayList`.

After passing that `ArrayList` to a servlet I can't retrieve all lines from the `ArrayList`. Also, I cant get all lines inside of a for loop. It prints a different amounts of line each time.

```
public class TextReader {

    public ArrayList<String> readText(InputStream file) {
        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList();
        try {
            InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr, 1024);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                lst.add(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

in servel i call

```
TextReader tr = new TextReader();
for (String text : tr.readText(new FileInputStream(file))) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr, 1024);` You are specifying a fixed size here....

Comment: For me it works well even with the fixed "1024"...

Comment: Do you really print 50000 lines to the console? Have you ever check if the list has the correct size? `tr.readText(new FileInputStream(file)).size()`?

Comment: @thomas yes 50000++ lines. When insee the size of list. It show 50000++ size. But i cant retrive it via arraylist or to console.

Comment: @kevin i tried without size and with size, but its not working

Comment: @Dzshean now I'm confused. Is the size of `tr.readText(new FileInputStream(file)).size()` the same as the size of the file (yes/no)?

Answer (score 0):

use BufferedReader without InputStreamReader. you can directly pass the file path parameter inside BufferedReader

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(<file path>);
```

Comment: cannot directly pass file path parameter to bufferdReader.it required a 'InputStreamReader'